# basic python issue using os.rename()

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to create a basic rename button using `os.rename()`.

This is what I have:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os
import sys

# make a list with selected objects
selectedObjects = cmds.ls(sl=True)

# loop over selected objects and add _geo
for item in selectedObjects:
    b = item.encode('utf-8')
    c = item + '_geo'
    os.rename(b, c)
```

I am getting an error with the `os.rename()`

> Error: WindowsError: file  line 9: 2

I guess it is a really simple error, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I just want a Python snippet that takes what I have selected and renames it to `_geo`.

Comment: What exactly is it your are trying to achieve? `os.rename` is for renaming files on your hard drive. It is not clear from the question that that is what you are trying to do

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick reply! I am trying to rename what I have selected in my maya scene. For example I select a geometry called thorus and with this python snippet I want to rename it to thorus_geo. How should I do that?

Comment: Maybe  [this will help](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/commandspython/rename.html#hExamples). Disclaimer: I have no clue how to use maya

Comment: great the cmds.rename method worked. Cheers :)